# Text containing math above and below equilibrium sign won't compile (using mhchem)

Tags: math-mode, equations, mhchem

Why won't this compile?  I suspect the math inside the `[]`s are preventing compilation.  If so how do I make this work?  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{E + S <=> [$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] ES <=>[$k_2$] E + P}
\end{document}
```

Error:

> ! Missing $ inserted.  
>                   $ l.34 ...k_1$}][\ce{$k_{-1}$}] ES <=>[$k_2$]
>   E + P}
>                                                      ?

Comment: set it without using math mode: `\ce{E + S <=> [k_1][k_{-1}] ES <=>[k_2] E + P}`

Comment: Very good, I also discovered the space between `<=>` and `[k_1][...` is not allowed. :|  Thanks!

Comment: @Herbert: since you answered first, post your comment as an answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: A gentleman huh?  ;)

Comment: I've unaccepted it, and you may proceed to delete if you wish, but I would credit both of you if I could.

Comment: @ptrcao: thanks. I've already delete it. Don't worry, Herbert answered first.

Comment: It also works with `\ensuremath{k_1}`, if you wish to have math mode for the common italic math font.

Comment: @Herbert: Please turn your comment into an answer -- you'll get reputation, and the list of unanswered questions will become shorter.

Comment: @lockstep: done

Answer (score 2):

set it without using math mode:

```
\ce{E + S <=> [k_1][k_{-1}] ES <=>[k_2] E + P}
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem)'s arrows already are in math mode. So wrapping them in `$...$` must go wrong.

```
\ce{A ->[\Delta] B} % default: math mode
```

If you would want or need text mode you'd have to use `\text{}` or mhchem's shortcut:

```
\ce{A ->T[text mode] B} = \ce{A ->[\text{text mode}] B}
```

Also there is a second shortcut for "chemistry mode", i.e. using the `\ce` macro:

```
\ce{A ->C[H2O] B} = \ce{A ->[\ce{H2O}] B}
```